# managed metadata navigation not working correctly

Tags: navigation, managed-metadata, metadata

I have created a managed metadata column in a library and pointed it to a term set.  I uploaded a single document and tagged it.

I have turned on the metadata navigation for this particular column.

in the navigation, when I click on the highest-level term and include all of the child terms, I get no results.  I'm certain I have selected all child terms based on the fact that they are highlighted.

when I drill down in the metadata navigation and click on the exact child term I now see my document.

This particular child term is 4 levels deep.

Any ideas why I can't see the document when I click on the highest-level parent term?

Comment: I have similar issue with you. I setup metadata navigation at a root site library, it works. However when I setup the same metadata navigation in a subsite library, metadata navigation is not working. I don't know why.

Comment: Check to see if the target page for the term is expired.

Answer (score 1):

Is the "Use this Term Set for Site Navigation" checked? You find this option in Term Store Management Tool.

Comment: This is not for the type of managed metadata navigation mentioned in the question (the one to filter lists). This is for the 2013 managed navigation, used for getting friendly URLs for publishing pages

Comment: True, I misunderstood.